# Compute value on the fly with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some RDBMS transactions stored as documents in my index.

Whenever I query the documents in elasticsearch, I need to check whether each document satisfies a particular condition(Example- i need to check if the document is older than 30 days) and should provide a value which implies if the document satisfies or not.

I have tried using 'script_fields' but dont know how to perform date computations.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
"query" : {
    "match_all": {}
},
"script_fields": {
  "test1": {
    "script": {
      "source": "doc['id'].value = 123"
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the query you're currently making

Comment: Please refer the query

Comment: I don't see your "document is older than 30 days" constraint in your query, please show what you've done

Comment: I can't find a way to play with date computations. which is what my question is. I can do string and integer comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need script fields for that, [date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) to the rescue:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "date_field" : {
                "lt" :  "now-30d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know about this. But my question is bit different. The query that I have posted will fetch all results but will provide a boolean value which tells us whether the document satisfies the condition(that is provided in script) or not.